# Symfony 3 rating form on several categories displayed on one page

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig, symfony-3.3

On some `Company` (entity) page I'm displaying several `Categories` (entity) which the Company might have. For every of the categories displayed I need to add simple form with rating value. So I've created entity Called `Rating` and I've generated `RatingType`.
Now I have the problem with display this form for each category displayed, I can display the form only once for the first `category` occurrence, but it in the `Rating` Form it can't get the name (the `id`) of the category which it should be connected.

The `Rating` entity have defined `Category` and `Company` in relation ManyToOne (@ORM).

I would appreciate for help how can I handle with that.

I suppose that the trick sits in the Controller, so below is my code:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/catalog/{id}.html", name="card_show")
     */
    public function cardShowAction(Company $company, Request $request)
    {
        $form = null;

        // @TODO: add verification if user is logged on => if ($user = $this->getUser()) 
        $rating = new Rating();
        $rating->setCompany($company);

        $form = $this->createForm(RatingType::class, $rating);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid() && $form->isSubmitted()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($rating);
            $em->flush();
            $this->addFlash('success', "Your vote has been saved!");

            return $this->redirectToRoute('card_show', array('id' => $company->getId()));
        }


        return $this->render("default/catalog/show.html.twig", array(
            'card' => $company,
            'form' => is_null($form) ? $form : $form->createView()
        ));
    }
```

Here is the `RatingType` code:

```
class RatingType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('comment')
                ->add('vote')
                // ->add('userName')
                // ->add('ip')
                // ->add('createdAt')
                ->add('service')
                // ->add('company')
                ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Rating'
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: show your form types please

Comment: I've added the `RatingType` class. I hope that this is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Each Symfony Form can be rendered in view only once (at least without nasty hacks).

I propose another approach. In your template render as many simple html forms (not binded with Symfony Forms at all!), as many categories you have. Then, give each of those form another action attribute (say "/catalog/{company_id}/category/{category_id}/vote"). Then, create new action, where you will parse, validate and use data from Request object.

If you really want to do all of this using Symfony forms you need to generate as many Symfony Forms instances, as many categories you will have. Each form needs to have unique name and action (or some hidden field) to distinct category user would like to vote.